# 2 submit buttons in the same line

Tags: html, css

I have two submit buttons part of two different forms, How can I display them in one common line and in the **middle** of the line side by side?

```html
<form action="https://google.com/search">
  <div style="display: inline;">
    <input id="google" type="text" name="q">
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Google Search">
  </div>
</form>
<form action="https://www.google.com/doodles/">
  <input class="button" type="submit" value="I'm so lucky">
</form>
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Sell you would need to make the forms inline....

Answer (score 2):

Make the forms inline with CSS

```css
.inline {
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<form action="https://google.com/search" class="inline">
  <div style="display: inline;">
    <input id="google" type="text" name="q">
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Google Search">
  </div>
</form>
<form action="https://www.google.com/doodles/"  class="inline">
  <input class="button" type="submit" value="I'm so lucky">
</form>
```

Other option is you can use the form id and target the form and put the button inside the other form.

```html
<form action="https://google.com/search">
  <input id="google" type="text" name="q">
  <input class="button" type="submit" value="Google Search">
  <input class="button" form="lucky" type="submit" value="I'm so lucky">
</form>
<form action="https://www.example.com" id="lucky"></form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Forms are `block` elements by default, you'll need to make these two `inline` for them to be on the same line.

Alternatively, wrap them in a `flex` container.

Answer (score 0):

You put your form on a `<div></div>` and on your CSS, past you div on [`display: flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox). I after, I've give a `margin-left` on the second button to get space between the button.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.ml-4 {
  margin-left: 4px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <form action="https://google.com/search">
    <div style="display: inline;">
      <input id="google" type="text" name="q">
      <input class="button" type="submit" value="Google Search">
    </div>
  </form>
  <form action="https://www.google.com/doodles/">
    <input class="button ml-4" type="submit" value="I'm so lucky">
  </form>
</div>
```

Learn the flexbox, now, it's really important! :)

Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex box to solve your problem

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
  <form action="https://google.com/search">
    <div style="display: inline;">
      <input id="google" type="text" name="q">
      <input class="button" type="submit" value="Google Search">
    </div>
  </form>
  <form action="https://www.google.com/doodles/">
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="I'm so lucky">
  </form>
</div>
```